# Return array from model to block not working in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

```
public function loadByField($field,$value)

{
     $table = $this->getMainTable();
     $where = $this->_getReadAdapter()->quoteInto("$field = ?", $value);
     $select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()->from($table,array('id'))->where($where);

     $id = $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchOne($select);
     // print_r($id);

     return $id;
}
```

This code is working well whenever I `print_r` directly on model and call function in block. But it is not working in return and get this value in block than get block in PHTML.

Comment: Which value it return in block currently?

Comment: Did you clear the Blocks output cache ?

Comment: @Dhiren Vasoya : its return Blank array in Block whenever i return from Model

Comment: @Attoui Ramzi : Yes Sir i have cleared all my browser cache

Comment: @YogeshKhasturi Im not talking about your browser cache, im talking about magento cache

Comment: @Attoui Ramzi  : Sir i have also cleared as well as Flashed magento caches